# How to add Access Control to Airflow Plugins that expose custom REST APIs

Tags: plugins, airflow, airflow-2.x

I'm using Airflow plugins to expose a custom REST API. This is done via Flask Blueprints and adding route to handlers. How can I add access controls similar to [Airflow REST APIs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/stable-rest-api-ref.html) for these custom APIs too?

```
import flask
import http
from airflow.www.app import csrf
from airflow import plugins_manager
import logging

LOG = logging.getLogger(__name__)

HELLO_BLUEPRINT = flask.Blueprint(
    'hello-api', __name__, url_prefix='/hello/v1/world')


@HELLO_BLUEPRINT.route('/', methods=['POST'])
@csrf.exempt
def hello_world() -> flask.Response:

    LOG.info('hello_world POST called')
    return flask.Response(status=http.HTTPStatus.OK, response="Hello World !")


class HelloApiPlugin(plugins_manager.AirflowPlugin):
    """Integrates our flask Blueprint."""
    name = 'hello_api'
    flask_blueprints = [HELLO_BLUEPRINT]
```

Airflow is setup for basic auth and triggering requests with a user with viewer role to the custom API returns a 200 OK unlike a 401 UNAUTHORIZED when making requests to say the Airflow REST API [trigger a DAGRun](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/stable-rest-api-ref.html#operation/post_dag_run).

Tried adding the security.requires_access decorator as seen in https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/api_connexion/endpoints/dag_run_endpoint.py#L294. But plugin fails to load with error "RuntimeError: Working outside of application context".